Anatomically Correct Imps
This is a submission for the Anatomically Correct Series. The purpose is to "describe fictional or mythological creatures from an evolutionary context with as much biological and behavioral realism as possible."

Image generated by Midjourney.
In my world, every mythological creature ever imagined exists. However, these creatures are devoid of magic and must be biologically plausible. Today, I focus on the Imp.
Originating from European folklore, the Imp is a winged entity dwelling in forests, caves, and even volcanic regions. Unlike bats, their arms are separate from their bat-like wings. They possess horns, a tail, and clawed extremities. Larger and heavier than any bat, they remain significantly smaller than an adult human.
Imps exhibit higher intelligence than most animals but do not match human intellect. Known for their mischief rather than danger, they pilfer food, wreak havoc on shelters, and have a penchant for shiny objects. Their societal structure is hierarchical, led by larger Imps. Humans residing nearby can domesticate them. Their diet resembles that of Flying Foxes.
Considering a planet akin to Earth, how might Imps have evolved from bats, given these traits?

"Originating from European folklore": citation needed. As in, I don't believe that the creature shown in that ultra-modern picture has anything to do with any kind of folklore. What is striking is that the word imp originally meant a young shoot of a tree; then it acquired the meaning "child"; and only in the 16th century did it began to mean "little demon". (And anyway, what is "European" folklore? Do you really believe that there is a deep folkloring layer uniting all European nations?)

This isn't an ACS question. How would X evolve is different than asking how to make X physically possible.

@AlexP"Do you really believe that there is a deep folkloring layer uniting all European nations?"; well, maybe not ALL, but definitely the ones originating from the Indo-Iranian migrations tend to have very similar mythology and folklore, further reinforced by the influence of the Roman Empire. Save for Finns, Hungarians, Basques and (mostly extinct) Picts, all Europeans can trace their culture to the same broad root.

@GoingDurden: There is no European nation originating from any Indo-Iranian migrations. Most European languages are Indo-European, but the IE branches which gave rise to the Indo-European languages of Europe separated from the Indo-Iranian branch about 7,000 years ago. (For reference, the Indo-Iranian languages are Persian, Pashto, Hindustani and such like.) (And language is not transmitted biologically. Two languages being related or not related does not tell much about the people who speak those languages. For example, most Hungarians are pretty typical Central Europeans genetically.)

I think you need an earlier divergence point. I can’t think of any instance of a mammal evolving additional limbs. That’s a colossal body plan alteration.

The [tag:anatomically-correct] tag wiki states, "Please apply this tag conservatively." You've asked six ACS questions....

@AlexP one could easily imagine a word like sprout going through a similar transformation, it's an element of world building you rarely see any more, and may only ever have been seen for a brief period around the 1960s and 70s perhaps?

@sphennings The series literally says  "describe fictional or mythological creatures from an evolutionary context with as much biological and behavioral realism as possible." That is functionally equivalent to "how would X evolve." Now you're just being pedantic. If you hate ACS questions (& I no longer care for them). Just admit it, or link to one that meets your standards.

@Rhymehouse No, it is not the equivalent of "how would X evolve?" The ACS describes how a mythical creature may be physiologically manifest in the real world. In other words, "if it evolved, what would its characteristics be?" That's a lot different than "how would X evolve?" which asks for millions of years worth of pressures, challenges, and opportunities to derive the result. The ACS was never intended to (and does not) answer that question.

I don't think it would be likely that imps could evolve into humanoids from bats, I find it much more likely that they evolved from humans or past close relatives to humans - though, convergent evolution isn't uncommon, so it isn't at all impossible. As for more physical traits, I think wings could have evolved from a second pair of arms which could've evolved from a sudden genetic mutation which ended up helping them climb trees/an extra pair of wings which evolved into arms that originally helped with better flying or steering. A tail also likely would have evolved for steering, though I thi

As bats spread into diverse environments (forests, caves, and volcanic regions), some populations may have evolved traits to exploit new ecological niches, leading to the evolution of Imps with distinct morphology.
Unlike traditional bats, Imps evolved wings separate from their arms, akin to the structure seen in pterosaurs. This adaptation would allow them to use their forelimbs independently for manipulation, climbing, or carrying objects, increasing their ability to interact with the environment and steal items.
For dexterity, their hands and feet would have clawed digits, enabling them to cling to branches, climb rocky surfaces, and manipulate objects. This would make them excellent climbers.
The evolution of horns might have occurred for defensive or mating display purposes. In a species where territorial disputes or dominance hierarchies exist, horns could signal strength and status. They might also help them look more intimidating to potential predators or competitors.
Evolving in an environment where they could scavenge and steal from other animals (and later humans), Imps would develop high intelligence levels relative to other animals. Their cognitive abilities might be similar to corvids (like crows and ravens).

Considering how sensitive the community is to ACS questions at this time, the fact that you have an answer to your own question (meaning you had no reason to ask this question) and that you presented that answer first (suggesting you're just rep farming) is very, very bothersome. You've asked six ACS questions, making you one of the most prolific querents in the series' history - but the point of the series is not to create an exhaustive catalog of creatures, but to provide an education. One you've obviously learned and so you need no longer ask for ACS help.

@JBH if users weren't supposed to answer their own questions, it wouldn't be an option. The point of stack exchanges isn't just to educate people asking questions, but to inform the multitude of lurkers who have similar questions.

You'd be correct if it was anything other than an ASC question. We expect people to learn from their experience with this site. You've obviously done that, so you're done asking ACS questions. You've officially entered the prohibited realm of mindless social fun (see [help/dont-ask]).
